# java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding error in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I am following a tutorial from [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html).
I have trying to make a RPC call from my module. But I am getting this error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'myPackageName.client.StockPriceService' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
```

My StockPriceService class is:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("stockPrices")
public interface StockPriceService extends RemoteService{

    StockPrice[] getPrices(String[] symbols) throws DelistedException;
}
```

StockPriceServiceAsync class is:

```
public interface StockPriceServiceAsync {

    void getPrices(String[] symbols, AsyncCallback<StockPrice[]> callback); 
}
```

My StockPrice class is:

```
public class StockPrice implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String symbol;
    private double price;
    private double change;

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public double getChange() {
        return change;
    }

    public void setChange(double change) {
        this.change = change;
    }

    public double getChangePercent() {
        return 100.0 * this.change / this.price;
    }

    public StockPrice(String symbol, double price, double change) {
        super();
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.price = price;
        this.change = change;
    }
}
```

I always get the error when the following line is execute in my  EntryPoint Class

```
private StockPriceServiceAsync stockPriceSvc = GWT.create(StockPriceService.class);
```

any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace, there would be root cause details

Comment: Can you post your StockPrice class

Comment: @Thillakan, updated. Check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StockPrice` must have a zero-argument constructor or no constructors at all for default initiation. Please check the stack trace and confirm.

Comment: yap. adding a zero-argument constructor solve this problem. cool.